# Use Popup Window in nested listviews

Tags: java, android, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm new to Android and in my app, I am trying to add in a function where a popup window appears when the user clicks on a layout formatted to look like a button.

The problem is that in the activity in which I would like to achieve this, I have listed listviews each adapting their own unique customized baseadapters.

I feel like that this is a very inefficient and heavy design for my app but I could not think of a better way to achieve my goal so far. All my other functions are working fine (as in terms of they are responding very well to "clicks"). I have also checked the visibility of popup window via logging `popup.isShown()`, which told me that it was true upon clicking the `layout`.

One thing I can guess of now is to pass the root view (the activity's view) to where I am making the popup window, but I don't think this is a good idea due to several reasons, which I believe one could be possible corruption/manipulation of data as I'm already passing much information via parameters to my "inner" adapters.

So, could any give me insights to a better and lighter structural design for my app and a solution to resolve my popup window problems? Thanks in adavance.

Simplified:

-My app has an activity named "CoffeeSelectActivity" where it presents a list of drinks the selected cafe provides (shown in listview with id "drinks_list"

-This listview is inflated with `item_cafe_menu`. In order to do this, I created a customized baseadatper named `DrinksItem`

-In `item_cafe_menu`, I have a listview showing the cups being selected and the specific options the client wishes to add (extra shot, etc.) that appears when the user clicks on a list item of `drinks_list`. For this, I make use of a private class inside `DrinksItem` named `Dropdown`

-In `Dropdown` class, I implement another customized baseadapter for my `dropdown_options_list` listview in `item_cafe_menu_dropdown.xml`, named `DropdownOptionsItem`. This populates the options available for selected drink with the option name followed by the option, for instance, selecting the size to be large instead of regular, the `dropdown_option_name` textview will show `Size` and the `dropdown_option_selected_option` textview will show `Large`.

-To achieve this functionality, I want to display a popup window when the user clicks on the `dropdown_option_selection_layout`. So I added an onclick event for this layout in `DropdownOptionsItem`, which current is not showing anything on my device, but the `Log` displays `true` for `isShowing()`

-I know this is a very nasty code so I would like to get insights to improving the code and making this popup window appear on the screen.

Code:

`CoffeeSelectActivity.java`

```
//code snipplet that sets adapter to my list
drinksListAdapter = new DrinksItem(this, menuList);
drinksList.setAdapter(drinksListAdapter);
```

`activity_coffee_select.xml`

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@id/drinks_list">
</ListView>
```

`DrinksItem.java`

```
package com.morning_coffee.morningmorning;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by user on 15. 10. 11..
 */
public class DrinksItem extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<DrinkInfo> drinkInfos;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public LinearLayout layout, dropdown;
        public TextView name, price;
    }

    public DrinksItem(Context context, ArrayList<DrinkInfo> drinkInfos) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.drinkInfos = drinkInfos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return drinkInfos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return drinkInfos.get(position).getDrinkName();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    //reuse views
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cafe_menu, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout);
        holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);
        holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_price);

        setOnClickEvents(convertView, holder, position);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    //fill data
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.name.setText(drinkInfos.get(position).getDrinkName());
    holder.price.setText(drinkInfos.get(position).getDrinkPrice());

    return convertView;
}

private void setOnClickEvents(final View view, final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.menu_dropdown_layout);

            if(viewHolder.dropdown == null) {
                //show dropdown menu
                viewHolder.dropdown = new Dropdown(context, drinkInfos, group, viewHolder.dropdown, position);

                //set bottom margin
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) viewHolder.layout.getLayoutParams();
                p.bottomMargin = 13;
            }
            else {
                //remove dropdown menu and clear child views from viewgroup
                viewHolder.dropdown = null;
                group.removeAllViews();

                //set bottom margin
                ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) viewHolder.layout.getLayoutParams();
                p.bottomMargin = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}

private class Dropdown extends LinearLayout {
    private ListView options;
    private ImageButton dec, inc;
    private Button basket;
    private TextView count;
    private ArrayList<DrinkInfo> info;

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ListView op;
        private ImageButton d, i;
        private Button b;
        private TextView c;
    }

    public Dropdown(Context context, ArrayList<DrinkInfo> info, ViewGroup group, View view, int position) {
        super(context);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(group.getChildCount() == 0) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cafe_menu_dropdown, group);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.d = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_decrement);
            holder.c = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_count);
            holder.i = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_increment);
            holder.op = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_options_list);
            holder.b = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_basket_button);

            String[] splitOptions = info.get(position).getDrinkOptions().split(":");
            DropdownOptionsItem adapter = new DropdownOptionsItem(context, Arrays.asList(splitOptions));
            holder.op.setAdapter(adapter);

            setOnClickEvents(holder, position);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        this.info = info;

        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.c.setText(info.get(position).getDrinkCount());
    }

    private void setOnClickEvents(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.d.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int t = Integer.parseInt(info.get(position).getDrinkCount());
                if(t > 1) {
                    info.get(position).setDrinkCount((t - 1) + "");
                    viewHolder.c.setText(info.get(position).getDrinkCount());
                }
            }
        });

        viewHolder.i.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    int t =     Integer.parseInt(info.get(position).getDrinkCount());

                    info.get(position).setDrinkCount((t + 1) + "");
                    viewHolder.c.setText(info.get(position).getDrinkCount());
                }
            });

            viewHolder.b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("dropdown vh", "basket");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`item_cafe_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@id/menu_layout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:id="@id/menu_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@id/menu_price" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@id/menu_dropdown_layout" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:background="#ffc8c8c8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`item_cafe_menu_dropdown.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="22.0dip"
                android:text="count"
                android:textSize="15.0dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/dropdown_decrement"
                android:src="@mipmap/btn_control_circlebtn_nor_minus"
                android:background="@null" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/dropdown_count"
                android:layout_width="54.0dip"
                android:layout_height="22.0dip"
                android:textSize="15.0dip"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/dropdown_increment"
                android:src="@mipmap/btn_control_circlebtn_nor_plus"
                android:background="@null" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/dropdown_options_list" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@id/dropdown_basket_button"
        android:text="Basket" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`DropdownOptionsItem.java`

```
package com.morning_coffee.morningmorning;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Created by user on 15. 10. 12..
 */
public class DropdownOptionsItem extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> options;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView name, option;
        public LinearLayout layout;
    }

    public DropdownOptionsItem(Context context, List<String> options) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.options = options;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return options.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return options.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        //initialize if convertView is null
        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_cafe_menu_dropdown_option, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_option_name);
            holder.option = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_option_selected_option);
            holder.layout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dropdown_option_selection_layout);

            setOnClickEvnets(holder, position);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        //fill data
        holder.name.setText(options.get(position));
        holder.option.setText(options.get(position+1));

        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return convertView;
    }

    private void setOnClickEvnets(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        viewHolder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(context);
                TextView tv = new TextView(context);
                tv.setText("popup");
                l.addView(tv);

                PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow();
                popup.setContentView(l);

                popup.getContentView().bringToFront();
                popup.showAsDropDown(viewHolder.layout);
                popup.setWidth(300);
                popup.setHeight(300);
                Log.d("popup", popup.isShowing() + "");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`item_cafe_menu_dropdown_option.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22.0dip"
            android:id="@id/dropdown_option_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_corners"
        android:id="@id/dropdown_option_selection_layout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="22.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="4.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15.0dip"
            android:id="@id/dropdown_option_selected_option" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/arrow_next_2"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue via using startActivityForResult